BSC token disapeared?
Hello I did swap a token the tx was a succes but can't find it on my wallet
tx : https://bscscan.com/tx/0x104b876d8d9b9334f82071f40255c1824dcb118bafeded8c5016dfb52cff4d16
But 1 min later I got that https://bscscan.com/tx/0x12dbe141b9201aa8fcb7dc78e38464524f7ca1773c33ba446147b908fff130c5
I don't understand what it is ? where is my money ?
thx for the help

here is the contract adress 0x178643532B83783EFd9FDF43b5767CCe6F6A7D90
the thing is I don't have it on my wallet I don't understand and I can't swap it back so

You had approved the contract 0x604f15490D43C910E888B9149560bD8bFb9Dbe02 in https://bscscan.com/tx/0x104b876d8d9b9334f82071f40255c1824dcb118bafeded8c5016dfb52cff4d16#eventlog
And the contract transfer your token in https://bscscan.com/tx/0x12dbe141b9201aa8fcb7dc78e38464524f7ca1773c33ba446147b908fff130c5#eventlog
do you know what project it is?

here is the contract adress 0x178643532B83783EFd9FDF43b5767CCe6F6A7D90
the thing is I don't have it on my wallet I don't understand and I can't swap it back so

You have approve it in the first transaction and the token was transfered to another address in the second

I did but nothing in my wallet, this not the first time I'm doing swaps but this is the first time i'm experiencing that time of stuff seems like my tokens are gone to an other wallet that is not mine

Looks like one of those totally fake "tokens", that doesn't have a transferFrom or any normal ERC20 functions, so that when the scammer makes the swap and it gets to the point  where it would usually revert for insufficient allowance it instead calls the fallback in the scam contract which does some obfuscated checks on the address and allows it to go through.
Seems the scam is getting you to buy it, and then using the tokens you bought to swap the thing that actually has value (the native coin or pegged stable) out of the pool.

